# When a button is clicked that decrements a value, how do you stop it decrementing into the negative range

Tags: javascript, button

(First question!)

I am (attempting to) create a clicker game. When a button is clicked, the gold value should decrement by 10. This works. However, I want to stop it decrementing at zero.

e.g (if button clicked || if gold count >= 0) do code. else: error message
(that is not actual code, just me thinking)

I have tried a few ways, none of which seem to work

Any ideas? (I am not entirely sure if this is possible, as when you click the button, it would decrement by that number and then check if value is zero? i think? Wouldnt that be an infinite loop?)

The variables of (BeggarCount, BeggarCost, oText and oCount) have all been previously defined in HTML. As i said, the code does work, it just dosent stop at zero

CODE:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var vButton = document.getElementById("AddBeggar");
            var vText = document.getElementById("BeggarCount");
            var vcText = document.getElementById("BeggarCost");
            var vcost = 10
            var vcount = 0;
            var vprice = 10;

            if (vButton.addEventListener('click') || ocount >= 10) {
                vText.innerHTML = vcount += 1;
                vcText.innerHTML = vcost += 1;
                oText.innerHTML = oincrement += 1;
                oText.innerHTML = ocount -= vprice;
                vprice += 1;
            }, false);
```

when i try this, simply nothing happens.

Comment: Change your if condition.
```if (vButton.addEventListener('click') && ocount >= 10)```

Comment: I would check when the button is clicked, the value of ocount. If the value is zero, don't perform your logic. If it is greater or equal to 10, do your logic. The OR condition you have is wrong.

Comment: Yeah i just realised :) however, even after i changed it it still dosent work? i am going to try Nik's answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just did it!!

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var vButton = document.getElementById("AddBeggar");
            var vText = document.getElementById("BeggarCount");
            var vcText = document.getElementById("BeggarCost");3
            var vcost = 10
            var vcount = 0;
            var vprice = 10;

            vButton.addEventListener('click', function(i, a) {
                if (ocount >= vcost) {
                    vText.innerHTML = vcount += 1;
                    vcText.innerHTML = vcost += 1;
                    oText.innerHTML = oincrement += 1;
                    oText.innerHTML = ocount -= vprice;
                    vprice += 1;
                }
            }, false);


        </script>
```

This code works!!

All variables are the same

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change your if clause checking the current value of gold like:

```
if (vButton.addEventListener('click')  && ocount >= 10) {
    vText.innerHTML = vcount += 1;
    vcText.innerHTML = vcost += 1;
    oText.innerHTML = oincrement += 1;
    oText.innerHTML = ocount -= vprice;
    vprice += 1;
}, false);
```

Comment: This piece of logic over here has bug: `if (vButton.addEventListener('click')  && ocount >= 10) {}, false);` **expect an assignment or function call, instead saw an expression**